# Objective-c, Google Maps draw a polygon within radius of 50 Kilometers from my current location

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, polygon

Hope all are doing well.

In an on going project, am using Google Maps and need to draw an overlay like the below attached image, where the overlay covers the radius of 50km region from my current location.

[image]
Appreciate your help, I've tried few links which show same like

[Inverted Polygon in GMSMapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20772500/inverted-polygon-in-gmsmapview)

Comment: Who downvote this question , please mention the reason as well so i can identify the issue

Comment: Hello there! Yeah, the way of doing it (or what I ended up doing anyways) was to get them from Google Maps manually, ie. If you tap on the anywhere on the map it'll show you the coordinate pair, I know it's dirty but it looks like it's still the only way.

Comment: I know if i tap on map , i can collect the cordinate and draw the map but the problem is i want the cordinate without tap on map

Comment: Yep, I wanted that too, But it's unfortunate that information apparently it's still unavailable. In my case I settled for that "dirty" option because it was good enough to perform the geofencing algorithm I needed at the time.

Comment: What can be best option to achieve same , any idea ?